How to set constraint for optimisation problem to keep to continuity of allocation problem?
I want to allocate 20 districts on a map to 4 institutions. Below are the data I have.

district = {'d1', 'd2', ..., 'd20'}

institution = {'i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4'}

distance_in_km = {
   'd1': [['i1', 3], ['i2', 3], ['i3', 7], ['i4', 8]],
   'd2': [['i1', 4], ['i2', 4], ['i3', 6], ['i4', 8]],
   'd3': [['i1', 3], ['i2', 4], ['i3', 8], ['i4', 9]],
   'd4': [['i1', 5], ['i2', 4], ['i3', 5], ['i4', 7]],
   'd5': [['i1', 5], ['i2', 5], ['i3', 6], ['i4', 7]],
   'd6': [['i1', 5], ['i2', 4], ['i3', 7], ['i4', 8]],
   'd7': [['i1', 5], ['i2', 3], ['i3', 5], ['i4', 6]],
   'd8': [['i1', 7], ['i2', 5], ['i3', 4], ['i4', 6]],
   'd9': [['i1', 6], ['i2', 6], ['i3', 5], ['i4', 5]],
   'd10': [['i1', 6], ['i2', 5], ['i3', 6], ['i4', 6]],
   'd11': [['i1', 5], ['i2', 6], ['i3', 6], ['i4', 6]],
   'd12': [['i1', 8], ['i2', 7], ['i3', 5], ['i4', 4]],
   'd13': [['i1', 9], ['i2', 8], ['i3', 6], ['i4', 6]],
   'd14': [['i1', 8], ['i2', 7], ['i3', 4], ['i4', 3]],
   'd15': [['i1', 10], ['i2', 9], ['i3', 4], ['i4', 2]],
   'd16': [['i1', 11], ['i2', 10], ['i3', 7], ['i4', 7]],
   'd17': [['i1', 11], ['i2', 9], ['i3', 6], ['i4', 4]],
   'd18': [['i1', 12], ['i2', 11], ['i3', 9], ['i4', 6]],
   'd19': [['i1', 1], ['i2', 4], ['i3', 8], ['i4', 10]],
   'd20': [['i1', 2], ['i2', 4], ['i3', 8], ['i4', 9]]
}

adjacency = {
   'd1': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd6'],
   'd2': ['d1', 'd2', 'd6'],
   'd3': ['d1', 'd3', 'd19', 'd20'],
   'd4': ['d4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8', 'd10'],
   'd5': ['d4', 'd6', 'd10', 'd11'],
   'd6': ['d1', 'd2', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7'],
   'd7': ['d4', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8'],
   'd8': ['d4', 'd7', 'd8', 'd9', 'd10'],
   'd9': ['d8', 'd9', 'd10', 'd11', 'd12', 'd13'],
   'd10': ['d4', 'd5', 'd8', 'd9', 'd10', 'd11'],
   'd11': ['d5', 'd9', 'd10', 'd11'],
   'd12': ['d9', 'd12', 'd13', 'd14', 'd15', 'd16'],
   'd13': ['d9', 'd12', 'd13', 'd16'],
   'd14': ['d12', 'd14', 'd15'],
   'd15': ['d12', 'd14', 'd15', 'd16', 'd17'],
   'd16': ['d12', 'd13', 'd15', 'd16', 'd17', 'd18'],
   'd17': ['d15', 'd16', 'd17', 'd18'],
   'd18': ['d16', 'd17', 'd18'],
   'd19': ['d3', 'd19', 'd20'],
   'd20': ['d3', 'd20', 'd19']
}

Each districts can only be allocated to one single institution. I know the relative travel distance matrix (20 by 4) and I know the adjacency relationship among the districts (20 by 20). The allocation is to be done using optimization solving problem (e.g. Pyomo), also with the constraint that allocation of the same hospitals must form a predefined number of continuous group of districts.
How can I include such constraint into the solver to achieve the optimization problem?
Thanks so much.
The difficulty I encountered is that the adjaceny describe here can only directly reflect the immediate relationship. Yet for the continuity constraint, I want to consider also all the assigned relationships. For example, if only d3, d19  and d20 are allocated to i1, then d3, d19 and d20 can form one single cluster. However, if d1 is also allocated to another i1 but d6 is allocated to i2, then the cluster for i1 would become [d1, d2, d3, d19, d20]
Illustration of Problem Setting, Desirable Output and Undesirable Output
def optimization_model():

    global assignments, assignments_0, total_service_df, details_df
    
    assignments = pd.DataFrame(columns=['district', 'institution', 'assignment'])
    assignments_0 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['district', 'institution'])
    total_service_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['institution', 'total_service'])
    details_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['district', 'institution', 'service', 'traveling_cost', 'service_x_travelling_cost'])
    sum_1 = 0
    sum_2 = 0

    model = ConcreteModel()
    
    # Define sets
    model.Districts= Set(initialize=district_df['district'].unique())
    model.Institutions = Set(initialize=institution_df['institution'].unique())
    
    # Define parameters
    model.Distance = Param(model.Districts, model.Institutions, initialize=distances_df.set_index(['district', 'institution'])['distance'].to_dict())
    model.ServiceVolume = Param(model.Districts, initialize=service_volume_df.set_index('district')['service_volume'].to_dict())
    model.ExistingAssignment = Param(model.Districts, model.Institutions, initialize=existing_catchment_df.set_index(['district', 'institution'])['indicator'].to_dict())
    
    # Define decision variables
    model.Assign = Var(model.Districts, model.Institutions, within=Binary)
    
    # Define objective function
    model.Costing = sum(model.Distance[ac, h] * model.ServiceVolume[ac] * model.Assign[ac, h] for ac in model.Districts for h in model.Institutions)
    model.Disruption = sum(abs(model.Assign[ac, h] - model.ExistingAssignment[ac, h]) for ac in model.Districts for h in model.Institutions)
    model.TotService = sum(model.ServiceVolume[ac] for ac in model.Districts)
    model.Objective = Objective(expr=(1 - alpha) * model.Costing + alpha * model.Disruption, sense=minimize)

    # Define constraints
    
    # Constraint 1 - Single assignment for each district
    model.one_institution_per_district = ConstraintList()
    for ac in model.Districts:
        model.one_institution_per_district.add(sum(model.Assign[ac, h] for h in model.Institutions) == 1)

    # Constraint 2 - Predefined assignments (Set by user)
    model.predefined_assignment = ConstraintList()
    for index, row in fixed_df_2.iterrows():
        model.predefined_assignment.add(model.Assign[row['district'], row['institution']] == row['indicator'])

    # Constraint 3 - Prohibited assignments (Auto generated)
    model.prohibited_assignment = ConstraintList()
    for index, row in prohibited_institution_df_2.iterrows():
        model.prohibited_assignment.add(model.Assign[row['c'], row['institution']] == row['indicator'])
            
    # Constraints 4 & 5 - Maximum and minimum capacities for each institution (Set by user)
    model.MaxCapacity = ConstraintList()
    model.MinCapacity = ConstraintList()
    
    for index, row in max_capacity_df.iterrows():
        h = row['institution']
        max_cap = row['max_capacity']
        model.MaxCapacity.add(sum(model.ServiceVolume[ac] * model.Assign[ac, h] for ac in model.Districts) <= max_cap)
    
    for index, row in min_capacity_df.iterrows():
        h = row['institution']
        min_cap = row['min_capacity']
        model.MinCapacity.add(sum(model.ServiceVolume[ac] * model.Assign[ac, h] for ac in model.Districts) >= min_cap)

    # Constraints 6 - Tolerance on Clusters of Districts (Set by user)
    ???
        
    # Solve the model
    solver = SolverFactory('cbc')
    solver.solve(model)

    # Record the assignments from the optimization model, which is also the first output .csv file
    for ac in model.Districts:
        for h in model.Institutions:
            assignments = pd.concat([assignments, pd.DataFrame({'district': [ac], 'institution': [h], 'assignment': round(value(model.Assign[ac, h]))})], ignore_index=True)
            if round(value(model.Assign[ac, h])) == 1:
                assignments_0 = pd.concat([assignments_0, pd.DataFrame({'district': [ac], 'institution': [h]})], ignore_index=True)

    # Create the second output dataframe with total service volume for each institution for subsequent output of .csv file
    total_service_volume = {h: sum(value(model.ServiceVolume[ac]) for ac in model.Districts if value(model.Assign[ac, h]) > 0.5) for h in model.Institutions}
    total_service_df = pd.DataFrame(list(total_service_volume.items()), columns=['institution', 'total_service'])

    # Create the third output dataframe with detailed information for subsequent output of .csv file
    details_data = []
    for ac in model.Districts:
        for h in model.Institutions:
            if value(model.Assign[ac, h]) > 0.5:
                service = value(model.ServiceVolume[ac])
                traveling_cost = model.Distance[ac, h]
                service_x_travelling_cost = service * traveling_cost
                details_data.append((ac, h, service, traveling_cost, service_x_travelling_cost))

    details_df = pd.DataFrame(details_data, columns=['district', 'institution', 'service', 'traveling_cost', 'service_x_travelling_cost'])
    
    return assignments, assignments_0, total_service_df, details_df



If you are looking for help with an optimization problem, it would be good to put more of your code into the question.  All you have here is data without any reflection of effort into setting the problem up.

That said, the concept you are probably looking for is "ensuring network connectivity with a linear program" because you wish to define a cluster (network) within a linear program and ensure it is well connected.  Here's a good reference.  I think if you went this approach, it would still be quite challenging to tackle multiple clusters:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203408/ensure-a-graph-is-connected-in-a-linear-programming-problem?newreg=122451b7e7d34f19a68d5a3621e06441

And what is the goal of optimization? The minimal distance between districts and institutions?

@StasSimonov. Yes, my goal is to minimize the distances between districts and institutions. Of course, I have other constraints, like I have maximum and minimum capacities of services for each institution to take up from the allocated districts. But as I want to simplify the problem so I reduced the problem here.

@AirSquid. Thanks for the advice. I have attached in the revised question stating the effort I have made to set up the optimization problem. For my problem currently encountered was to set up the sixth constraint.

And how about adding the sums of distances between the cluster' districts to the objective function?

@StasSimonov You mean by adding that we can also minimizing the relative distances between clusters' districts? But like the example in my attached picture you can see that the second example, though undesirable, is so close to the other clusters of districts so I am afraid adding such element to the objective function may not be able to exclude such scenario.
